# mounting external exfat drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, lubuntu, hard-drive

trying to mount an external samsung 1TB HD formatted ExFat

It works r/w on OSX and Windows 7.

This is a fresh install on an old Dell Dimension 3000 with 70 gig HD and probably 512 ram. running Lubuntu.

I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/~/~: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/~/~"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

as long as i can read write on Windows and Lubuntu (transferring media from desktop to this lubuntu to create small server) im set, makes no difference if i have to erase the drive and use a different format.

bonus: what do i call this os if i want to be more general in terms of unix or linux or what? if i want to be unspecific when referring to this type of OS

Answer (score 3):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

and it will work.